# angular-bootstrap-calendar TypeError: d is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the calendar to work on my ionic app, installed the calendar and moment.js via bower but i'm getting the error where it's saying TypeError: d is not a function. and it brings me to the line "var previousDate = moment(vm.viewDate);" in mwlCalendar.js:35

```js
.controller('profileCtrl', function($scope, $state, User, calendarConfig, moment) {


//Calendar Stuff
$scope.calendarView = 'day';
$scope.viewDate = new Date();
var test = new Date('9/20/2016');
console.log(moment());
$scope.calendarTitle = "Test Calendar";

//test data
$scope.events = [{
  title: 'My event title', // The title of the event
  startsAt: new Date(2016, 10, 1, 1), // A javascript date object for when the event starts
  endsAt: new Date(2016, 10, 26, 15), // Optional - a javascript date object for when the event ends
  color: { // can also be calendarConfig.colorTypes.warning for shortcuts to the deprecated event types
    primary: '#e3bc08', // the primary event color (should be darker than secondary)
    secondary: '#fdf1ba' // the secondary event color (should be lighter than primary)
  },
  actions: [{ // an array of actions that will be displayed next to the event title
    label: '<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>', // the label of the action
    cssClass: 'edit-action', // a CSS class that will be added to the action element so you can implement custom styling
    onClick: function(args) { // the action that occurs when it is clicked. The first argument will be an object containing the parent event
      console.log('Edit event', args.calendarEvent);
    }
  }],
  draggable: false, //Allow an event to be dragged and dropped
  resizable: false, //Allow an event to be resizable
  incrementsBadgeTotal: true, //If set to false then will not count towards the badge total amount on the month and year view
  cssClass: 'a-css-class-name', //A CSS class (or more, just separate with spaces) that will be added to the event when it is displayed on each view. Useful for marking an event as selected / active etc
  allDay: false // set to true to display the event as an all day event on the day view
}];
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar" ng-hide="profile">

  <mwl-calendar view="calendarView" view-date="viewDate" events="events" view-title="calendarTitle">
  </mwl-calendar>
</div>
```

Comment: Posting the rest of the code around it might help the reader see exactly what's going on.  Right now it would be impossible for anyone external to see what's going on.  Also, I would suggest trying to use Chrome, go into the developer mode and single stepping through the code.  It may take some time for you to learn how to debug with Chrome but it's worth it.

Comment: posted what my html and controller is for the calendar

Comment: Post it as an answer to yourself if the audience might find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Found my issue, i was loading my sources for angular-bootstrap-calendar before momentjs